# Change values of a columns according to vlaues of another

Tags: r

I am new in R and I have a question. I have two data frames, and I want to change the values of a column in the second data frame based on the values of a column in the first data frame. Both columns are string and contain 4 numbers separated by (-). Here is an example,

[image]

So, based on this example, column b of Table 2 should change in a way that, if the first and last numbers in each set are equal then replace the values in Table 1. Also if a cell exists in column b of table 2 which the first and last numbers do not exist in table 1, delete that row (in this example: 2-201-2012-250).

Thank you

Comment: Please post the sample data frame with ```dput()```. It will make things easier.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for :

```
library(stringr) #for str_split()
library(dplyr) #for left_join()
my_df <- data.frame("a" = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                "b" = c("7-1-1-100", "7-1-1-12", "31-1-1-5", "31-1-1-8"),
                "c" = c(0, 0, 0, 0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_df2 <- data.frame("a" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 "b" = c("7-1-1-100", "7-1-1-12", "2-1-1-250", "31-1-1-5", "31-1-1-8"),
                 "c" = c("ABC", "ABCD", "AD", "ABV", "CDF"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my_var <- str_split(string = my_df$b, pattern = "-", n = 4, simplify = TRUE)
my_var2 <- str_split(string = my_df2$b, pattern = "-", n = 4, simplify = TRUE)

my_df$d <- paste(my_var[, 1], my_var[, 4], sep = "-")
my_df2$d <- paste(my_var2[, 1], my_var2[, 4], sep = "-")

my_df <- left_join(my_df[, c("a", "b", "d")], my_df2[, c("d", "c")], by = "d")

my_df <- my_df[, c("a", "b", "c")]
```